# How to get entire table data or multiple rows returned from a function in PG/PLSQL with pgAdmin 4.2.?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

**I tried using setof and table.** While creating function in **pgAdmin 4.2** there is no return type called setof or table. If I create function with setof and table name as a selected return type, it only returns one row of table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION pgsql_returnrecords() RETURNS SETOF RECORD(name char, city, char, id integer) AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
 rec RECORD;
BEGIN
select name,city,id INTO rec from test;
return next rec;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

I want my function to return table data with all rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either `returns setof record` or `returns table(....)` or `setof table_name` With `returns setof record` you have to specify the column names when *using* the function.

You are also not returning a complete result, because you only fetch a single row, put it into the record and return that.  To return a real "set" you need to use `return query` in PL/pgSQL. But such a function is much better written as a SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pgsql_returnrecords() 
  RETURNS table(name text, city text, id integer) 
AS 
$BODY$
  select name,city,id 
  from test;
$BODY$ 
language sql;
```

If you want to always return a complete row from the table `test` you can simplify that using `returns setof test` instead of `returns table(..)`

```
CREATE FUNCTION pgsql_returnrecords() 
  RETURNS setof test
AS 
$BODY$
  select *
  from test;
$BODY$ language sql;
```

Or, if you insist on PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pgsql_returnrecords() 
  RETURNS table(name text, city text, id integer) 
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
return query
  select name,city,id   
  from test;
END;
$BODY$ 
language plpgsql;
```

In both cases you have to use the function like a table in the FROM clause:

```
select *
from pgsql_returnrecords() ;
```

Comment: But pgAdmin4.2 doesn't accept table or setof test as a return type.

Comment: @Gauri: I don't know what you mean with "accept". The SQL in my answer is valid, just run it to create the function

Comment: I got the result from your second code. Thanks. I needed to set "Returns a set" to YES in options while creating a function.